# PHP IMAP mail "Disposition-Notification-To" header - mark as sent

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm building a small webmail system, and working on the "Disposition-Notification-To" header, to send a delivery receipt to who asked for it on received mail.

The question is:

- how to send it only once? how do I know it was already sent, and doesn't ask/send again?

Any ideas?

Something like a flag, like "Unseen", but "Delivery-Receipt-Sent", how to do that?

Must I have to use a database for that? No other way?

Comment: practically no client will use "Disposition-Notification-To", most users have it disabled, most webmail just strip it, many isp's strip it. another mail feature ruined by spammers

Comment: Been doing some tests, and it works on Horde and Outlook 2013. What is your advice?

Comment: the currently industry standard for "was that mail opened" is an  'invisible' image hosted on a server with  tracking id. And that fails a lot of time. there is simply is no reliable way to determine if email was opened

Comment: ok, i know that, what i want is to sent the receipt only once. Something like "Unseen" / "Answered" flag.

Comment: you could use the 'image' trick, but no guarantees

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 3503](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3503) talks about using the `$MdnSent` keyword as a pretty standard way of doing this. Don't invent custom keyword names if at all possible.

As for how to set these keywords on messages via PHP, you might want to read the PHP's IMAP library documentation. There is a function which stores these keywords/flags on the server.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do that, but with no success: 
$status = imap_setflag_full($this->connection, $this -> messageNumber, '\\$MdnSent');
and looks like i´m using Courier MTA, and i found this:
http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/README.imapkeywords.html
Custom flags / keywords are written on a file..

Comment: I'm not sure what made you think that adding a backslash is a good idea.

Comment: i tried several ways, with backslash as "\\Seen", and no backslash.. none of them worked..

Comment: And what happened if you use exactly ``$MdnSent`` as I told you?

Comment: Nothing. Only the default flags ("\\Seen", "\\Answered", .. ) work.

Answer (score -1):

Use a flag. To find messages for which you want to send:

```
a uid search header "disposition-notification-to" "@" not keyword sentdnt
```

And then when you send:

```
b uid store 321312 +flags.silent sentdnt
```

In an ideal world you would coordinate the flag name with other clients that do this.

Comment: I think i get the point, but what to do that with PHP, and i think i already tried addding custom flags and it didin´t worked..

Comment: Well, if you can't use flags, you'll have to use a database.